What is the best machine learning library for making a cancer detection model?
Every day, cancer and other disease rates continue to rise in our modern society, so I'd like to bring more attention and awareness to these problems, as they cause thousands of deaths every year. So my question is this: What is the best machine learning library for making a cancer detection model?
If anybody knows a good cancer dataset I can use and a quality youtube tutorial or blog that outlines the process from start to finish, please post it here.

couldnt recommend a dataset cause it totally depends on what cancer u are looking for , which cancer affect what organs is your project based upon and what needs does the project u want is based upon this is important
then i would suggest image classification with neural networks either in pytorch , tensorflow to build your model. do get back with what u have chosen and ill guide you  through what u can do next
